# Awkward space in references section

Tags: cross-referencing

Overleaf is splitting my references section into multiple pages for some reason. Any tips here?

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}


\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\setcellgapes{2pt}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\raggedbottom
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{upquote}


\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem{c1} Aggarwal, Rajesh and Andrew Samwick (1999). “The Other Side of the Tradeoff: The Impact of 
Risk on Executive Compensation.” Journal of Political Economy 107(1): 65-105.
\bibitem{c2} Bebchuk, Lucian, Jesse Fried, \& David Walker (2002). “Managerial Power and Rent Extraction 
in the Design of Executive Compensation.” The University of Chicago Law Review, 69: 751-846.
\bibitem{c3} Berle, Adolf and Gardiner Means (1932). The Modern Corporation and Private 
Property. New York, Macmillan Publishing Co.
\bibitem{c4} Boschen, John and Kimberly Smith (1995). “You Can Pay Me Now and You Can Pay Me Later: 
The Dynamic Response of Executive Compensation to Firm Performance.” The Journal of Business 68(4): 577-608.
\bibitem{c5} Greg, Jewell, and Tonks (2011). “Executive Pay and Performance: Did Bankers’ Bonuses Cause 
the Crisis?” International Review of Finance 12(1): 89-122.
\bibitem{6} Greg, Jewell, and Tonks (2005) "Executive Pay and Performance in the UK 1994-2002" Centre for Market and Public Organisation. Working Paper. 
1994-2002
\bibitem{c7} Hall and Liebman (1998) “Are CEOs Really Paid Like Bureaucrats?” The Quarterly Journal of 
Economics 113(3): 653-691.
\bibitem{c8} Hallock, Kevin and Paul Oyer (1999). “The Timeliness of Performance Information in 
Determining Executive Compensation.” Journal of Corporate Finance 5(9): 303-321.
\bibitem{c9} Harris, M. \& Raviv, A. (1977) "Optimal Incentive Contracts with Imperfect Information." 
Working Paper \#70-75-76, Graduate School of Industrial Administration, Carnegie-Mellon University.
\bibitem{c10} Holmstrom, Bengt (1979). “Moral Hazard and Observability.” Bell Journal of Economics 10(1): 
74-91.
\bibitem{c11} Jensen, Michael, and Kevin Murphy (1990). “Performance Pay and Top-Management 
Incentives.” Journal of Political Economy 98(2): 225-264.
\bibitem{c12} Jensen, Michael \& William Meckling (1976). “Theory of the firm: Managerial behavior, 
agency costs and ownership structure.” Journal of Financial Economics 3(4): 305-360.
\bibitem{c13}Joskow, Paul, Nancy Rose, and Catherine Wolfram (1996). “Political Constraints on Executive 
Compensation: Evidence from the Electric Utility Industry.” Rand Journal of Economics 27(1): 165-182.
\bibitem{c14}Leonard, Jonathan (1990). “Executive Pay and Firm Performance.” Industrial and Labor 
Relations Review 43(3): 13S-29S.
\bibitem{c15}Mirrlees, J. (1976) "The Optimal Structure of Incentives and Authority within an Organization." 
The Bell Journal of Economics, 7 (1): 105.
\bibitem{c16}Ozkan, Neslihan (2011). “CEO Compensation and Firm Performance: An Empirical 
Investigation of UK Panel Data.” European Financial Management 17(2): 260-285.
\bibitem{c17}Shavell, S. (1979) "Risk Sharing and Incentives in the Principal and Agent Relationship." The 
Bell Journal of Economics, 10 (1): 55.
\bibitem{c18}Wallsten, Scott (2000). “Executive Compensation and Firm Performance: Big Carrot, Small 
Stick.” Working Paper. 99-017.  

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: With your MWE (after adding the missing `\begin{document}`) I get all references correctly in the same page. Please provide a MWE that *actually* shows the problem.

Comment: Did you create the contents of the `thebibliography` environment by hand, or did you use a software tool? Please advise.

Comment: Off-topic, but the quotations marks look odd. All the opening ones are upside down.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Now it is working for me too. It must have been a temporary spacing thing but as I added to the paper it shuffled itself into place.

Comment: @samcarter you are correct. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @texmex You could change them in your code to `\bibitem{c1} Aggarwal, Rajesh and Andrew Samwick (1999). ``The Other Side of the Tradeoff: The Impact of 
Risk on Executive Compensation.'' Journal of Political Economy 107(1): 65-105.`  (or maybe the `csquotes` package can help)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as problem vanished on its own :)